# Alternative to grub

Tags: boot, grub2

On my nettop (nvidia ion) grub takes ~2 min to load (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/443113).
Can I use some alternative bootloader to work around this issue?
How to set it up?

Comment: LILO is the other loader that gets a bit of attention. You could look into that.

Comment: That doesnt look like a grub problem - it looks like a kernel issue.  Does post #34 work for you?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the @13east answer, there is the very good and very simple [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/).

I also want to share the very good answer of @mikeserv on [Unix & Linux Stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146784/is-grub-the-best-bootloading-solution-is-there-an-easier-alternative#answer-146803) to a similar question *Is GRUB the best bootloading solution? Is there an easier alternative?*.

Finally if you are looking for more exotic choices you can take a look on [alternativeto](http://alternativeto.net/software/grub/).

Answer (score 2):

Some alternatives to GRUB would be:

1. [BURG = Brand-new Universal loadeR from GRUB](http://code.google.com/p/burg/)
2. [GAG = initials in spanish of Graphical Boot Manager](http://gag.sourceforge.net/)
3. [LILO = LInux LOader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LILO_%28boot_loader%29)
4. [Syslinux = lightweight bootloaders for MS-DOS FAT filesystems and Linux ext2/ext3/ext4 or btrfs filesystems (EXTLINUX)](http://syslinux.zytor.com/wiki/index.php/The_Syslinux_Project)

If you're having problems with GRUB, I would recommend staying away from grapical bootloaders like BURG and GAG but you can try them all to see which fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I coded [grub-smart](https://gitlab.com/es20490446e/grub-smart), which makes GRUB to automatically figure out its optimal configuration.