# Choosing bootloader (dual boot)

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, bootloader

I have removed Ubuntu on My Laptop Because I hate the way of GRUB bootloader.
I completely prefer windows8 bootloader instead of Ubuntu (grub).

I want to Install Ubuntu again when I know how to change the bootloader...
I have searched on internet but I assume that the dual boot (Win8-Linux) explained is alongside windows not installed in separated Partition.

so when I turn on the Laptop, it would boot just like windows8 boot but have an option :
Windows 8
Ubuntu

then it will boot normally whatever I choose (win8 or Ubuntu)

plus I want to make sure, Can I Install Gnome Desktop Environment on Ubuntu (not Ubuntu Gnome)

Please Help. Many thanks.

Comment: Please don't ask 2 questions in one question.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to have Ubuntu in the Windows 8 boot loader. However, you can look at [some alternatives to GRUB](https://askubuntu.com/a/53690/134848).

Answer (score 0):

Yes You Can By Using EasyBSD (On your windows)

Download EasyBSD Here: http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/EasyBCD.shtml

Then Just Fix Your Bootloader and then just reboot back into ubuntu (Grub will show) and do the following:

Open A Terminal Window And Type: `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
and change   `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0` (Not hidden timeout)

After you did that just go back to your terminal windows and type in: `sudo update-grub`

Enjoy!!!

Please Click Solved And My Answer if my answer was Helpful and/or Solved your issue

Answer (score 0):

Well I would have to say that there is no possible way in getting this objective. I had the same problem as you. There is a program within the Ubuntu Software Store that is awesome and might be your answer toward your problem. The program is called "Grub Customizer". Here is a picture. With this program you can change the grub setup. Check it out, you'll love it and won't have problems. The features with with program is changing kernel versions, changing the grub background and has a good gui. Hopefully this will help with your problem.[image: Picture of program]