# Load Ubuntu without GRUB, Is it possible?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, bootloader

I have two partitions. The first partition contains Windows. I use a second partition for Ubuntu without GRUB.

How can I make Windows bootloader can detect Ubuntu? I do not want to use GRUB.

Is it possible to create an ISO file that acts as a bootloader for Ubuntu? Or put GRUB in an ISO file?

Comment: dupe: http://askubuntu.com/questions/62440/is-it-possible-to-boot-ubuntu-using-the-windows-bootloader 1st answer uses grub2 from within windows bootloader. Also here a list of alternatives: http://askubuntu.com/questions/53686/alternative-to-grub

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Wubi` to install ubuntu on your system. **Wubi** is Ubuntu installer for Windows. By using **Wubi** you can install, uninstall, and manage Ubuntu from windows.

All instructions are [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi)

`Wubi.exe` still exists in `Ubuntu` images.

Comment: Last supported version of wubi is 12.04, best not to use it unless very experienced with newer versions.

Comment: `Wubi.exe` still exists in Ubuntu `iso` images .

Answer (score 0):

About the iso file that act as a bootloader to Ubuntu, I beleave that you mean a boot disk. It's possible, and exist the [Super Grub Disk 2](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/), that can be used for that.